# Is it possible to run the script when the sheet is added to google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know we can run the script on ONCLICK and ONEDIT....
I want to run my Google apps script when the worksheet added to my existing spreadsheet...
This script should modify some contents in the newly added sheet...

Is it possible?
If so please tell me how...

Answer (score 1):

One way I've managed to do this is to define a trigger on the On Change event of the spreadsheet and call the `onChange` function shown below:

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onChange(e) {
  var _changeType = e.changeType, _ss = e.source, _newss;
  Logger.log(_changeType);
  if(_changeType === 'INSERT_GRID') {
    _newss = _ss.setActiveSheet(_ss.getSheets()[_ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex()]);
    Logger.clear();
    Logger.log(_newss.getName());
  }
}
```